# accessing classes from a .h file in C++

Tags: c++

Hello I am new to using header files and OPP in my programs and I am wondering why visual studio 2010 is stating that there are errors in my code. The code compiles and runs as desired but there are red lines under all of the objects

here are the header files

```
//functions.h
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class vehicle
{
public:
    int hp;
    int ammo;
    void displayHP();
    void displayAmmo();
    void displayName();
    string vesselName;
    void setName(string);
    void moveUP(int& y);
    void moveDown(int& y);
    void moveLeft(int &x);
    void moveRight(int &x);
private:
};

//implementation section
void vehicle::displayHP() { cout << hp << endl; }
void vehicle::displayAmmo() { cout << ammo << endl; }
void vehicle::setName(string name) { vesselName = name; }
void vehicle::displayName() { cout << vesselName << endl;}

void vehicle::moveUP(int& y)
{
    y = y - 1;//moves boat up
    system("cls");  
}
void vehicle::moveDown(int& y)
{
    y = y + 1;//moves boat down
    system("cls");
}
void vehicle::moveLeft(int &x)
{
    x = x - 1;// moves the boat left
    system("cls");      
}

void vehicle::moveRight(int &x)
{
    x = x + 1;//moves boat right
    system("cls");
}
```

Here is the header file that contains the boats movements. I'm confused why visual studio is claiming there are so many errors (I added line comments to where the errors are) in this boat.h file

```
//boat.h
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include <string>
#include "functions.h"

using namespace std;

void moveBoat(int &x, int& y, int, int, int, int);
void youScrewedUp(int &x, int& y, int, int, int, int);

void moveBoat(int &x, int& y, int a, int b, int s, int turn)
{
    int movement = 0;

    vehicle destroyer;
    destroyer.hp = 500; //<==== getting a red line under the word destroyer error   says "this declaration has no storage class or type specifier"
    destroyer.ammo = 500; // ditto
    
    displayArray(x,y,a,b,s); //ditto
    destroyer.setName("USS YAY I LEARNED CLASSES"); //ditto
    destroyer.displayName(); //ditto
    destroyer.displayHP(); //ditto

    cout << "Boat Location X " << x << " Y " << y << endl;

    if (s==1)
    {
        cout << "ENEMY SHIP SIGHTED" << endl; //<===="this declaration has no storage class or type specifier"
    }
    cout << "1.move left" << endl; //ditto
    cout << "2.move right" << endl; //ditto
    cout << "3.move up" << endl; // ditto
    cout << "4.move down" << endl;// ditto
    cin >> movement; // ditto

    switch(movement) //<==expected a deceleration 
    {
        case 1:
            if (x > 0)//does not allow boat to leave grid
            {
                destroyer.moveLeft(x);
            }
            else
            {
                youScrewedUp(x,y,turn,a,b,s);// function that repeats the movement function and displays a message
            }
            break;

        case 2:
            if (x < 9)//boundary
            {
                destroyer.moveRight(x);
            }
            else
            {
                youScrewedUp(x,y,turn,a,b,s);
            }
            break;

        case 3:
            if (y > 0)//boundary
            {
                destroyer.moveUP(y);
            }
            else
            {
                youScrewedUp(x,y,turn,a,b,s);
            }
            break;

        case 4:
            if (y < 9)//boundary
            {
                destroyer.moveDown(y);
            }
            else
            {
                youScrewedUp(x,y,turn,a,b,s);
            }
            break;  
    }
    turn++;//adds one to the turn counter to cycle to the enemies turn
}

void youScrewedUp(int &x, int &y, int turn, int a, int b, int s)
{
    cout << "where are you going your leaving the battlefield" << endl;
    cout << "please make another selection" << endl;
    system("pause");
    system("cls");
    moveBoat(x,y,turn,a,b,s);
}
```

Here is my main()

```
// arrayTest.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
//

#include "stdafx.h"
#include "array.h"
#include "boat.h"
#include "enemy.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int turn=1;// turn counter cycles between 1 and 2 during player and enemy turns
    int x=7; //x coordinate for destroyer
    int y=6; //y coordinate for destroyer            
    int a=3; //x coordinate for sub
    int b=4; //y coordinate for sub
    int s=0; //toggle for submerged or not chose not to use a bool because I used a random number generator to allow a 25% chance opposed to a 50% chance
    srand (time(NULL));

    do {
        moveBoat(x, y, turn, a, b, s);
        moveEnemy(a, b, turn, x, y, s);
    } while (turn < 3);// this is temporary will be replaced when a hp and weapons system is completed
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: you need to put your code inside the `main()`

Comment: Did you say MSVC accepted this code?

Comment: You should read a book about C++ instead. Because what you do is not good at all. Possibly one of [those](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)

Comment: I just posted my main() on the bottom of the original post I believe i have properly declared the variables and functions within the classes I could be wrong seeing as I am new to this and that is why I am asking for the wisdom of stack overflow...

Comment: @faranwath yes It compiles fine and runs the way it should in visiual studio 2010 It is just throwing red lines and all sorts of other wierdness at me in the editor Its bothering me because typically with those types of error notifications in the editor it will not compile.

Comment: @JohnSnow: Nope, that cannot compile. The contents of `boat.h` render this program illegal.

Comment: you need to put the content in `boat.h` inside a function

Comment: @faranwath.... I can send you a screenshot it compiles

Comment: @JohnSnow: Are you entirely, positively sure that you compiled the program you showed us?

Answer (score 4):

This goes beyond your base question and adds some other things that will improve your code and hopefully understanding.

1. You need to put your 'main' function  code literally in a main function

   ```
   int main(int argc, char * argv[])
   {
       //do stuff here....
       return 0;
   }
   ```
2. You should include header guards to prevent you from including 'function.h' multiple times.  I would also strongly suggest renaming it to `Vehicle.h` to be emblematic of the class it is providing.

   ```
   #ifndef __VEHICLE_H__
   #define __VEHICLE_H__
   //... all the good stuff.

   #endif
   ```
3. I would STRONGLY suggest you remove `using namespace std` from your header file as doing so will trash the namespaces of anyone who wishes to use your header.  Instead simply use `std::` where needed or if you really don't want to use them everywhere, consider doing a `using std::xyz;` for the specific features you are using.  This way at least you can trace down collisions later.  If you want to do this in an implementation file (i.e. `*.c`) that's up to you; but don't do it in files that are included generally speaking.
4. Don't include headers you aren't using in your header file. This is a bad habit, leads to code and compiler bloat, and will inevitably cause pain later.  You shouldn't be including `ctime` or `stdafx` in each of your headers as they don't refer to it.
5. You need to put the body of 'stuff' that is floating inside `boat.h` into a function

   ```
   //somefunct
   void somefunction()
   {
       int movement=0;

       vehicle destroyer;
       destroyer.hp=500;//<==== getting a red line under the word destroyer error   says "this deceleration has no storage class or type specifier"
       destroyer.ammo=500;//<==== getting a red line under the word destroyer error   says "this deceleration has no storage class or type specifier"


       //.... Everything else

   }
   ```

Comment: I apologize... this question was absolutely not necessary I accidentally copied half of a function to the functions.h header file and left some behind... I apologize for wasting anybodies time

Comment: Not a total waste, every thing else I said still applies. Learn what you can from every experience :-)

Comment: Yes and thank you for the advice... I don't really know why I was trying to move to the functions.h file all the code applied to the boat.h anyway... I think I was doing it for down the line inheritance things like damage and attacks. I would remove the namespace std; from the program but it is going to be for a class final where using namespace std; is a class requirement... could you enlighten me and tell me why it is bad practice?

Comment: using namespace std is fine in your `main` but it is horrible in a header file, and anyone who tells you otherwise is suspect.  Honestly I tend to imagine you misunderstand the requirement.  The problem is this: let's say I define a method called `xyz` and use it in a header and implementation of my own.  Then you want to include my stuff into your project.  If `xyz` existed in the std namespace you'd have a collision.  This brings up all sorts of other problems that you should search or ask your teacher about.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice

Comment: +1 for making the effort to salvage the unsalvageable.